# Cannot see the default landing tab option in a custom Console app

Tags: app, console

I have created a custom console app, in that app , i could not see the option to set the "Default landing tab" for the app.  (I have unchecked the option 'Save user session' in app properties)

Every time the users logout and login back, they should be taken to the "Home" tab as the default landing tab in the app.

However Salesforce is taking them to the last tab which they were using before they logged out last time.

Any suggestions of how to set the default landing tab for a custom console app.